# How to put password during unistallation of application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

While uninstalling any application in windows phone 7 user must enter a password ? i mean how to make application as password protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to stop the user from uninstalling an application.

Comment: And a good thing it is, too.  I would be unhappy if a developer decided he knew better than I did whether I wanted his/her software on my device.